# Writing a test data builder with syntax

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, builder-pattern

Is it possible to write a TestDataBuilder which follows a given syntax?

So for example:

[image: Carbuilder]

I know how to write a basic builder for a car that's not the problem.

**But how can I achieve, that I can only add new windows to a door?**

So this is allowed:

```
var car = CarBuilderWithSyntax.Create()
              .WithDoor()
                  .HavingSide(Sides.Left)
                  .WithWindow()
                      .HavingWidth(50)
                      .HavingHeight(50)
            .Build();
```

But this is **not** allowed:

```
var car = CarBuilderWithSyntax.Create()
              .WithWindow()
                  .HavingWidth(50)
                  .HavingHeight(50)
          .Build();
```

Is there a possibility to enforce this syntax-rule?

Can this be achieved by using an additional door builder which inherits car builder?

Should the car builder implement different interfaces like IDoorBuilderWithSyntax which defines the methods `ICarBuilderWithSyntax WithWindow()` and `ICarBuilderWithSyntax HavingSide();` `ICarBuilderWithSyntax HavingColor()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
public enum Sides
{
    Left,
}

public class Car
{

}

public class CarBuilderWithSyntax
{
    protected CarBuilderWithSyntax ParentBuilder { get; private set; }

    public static CarBuilderWithSyntax Create()
    {
        return new CarBuilderWithSyntax(null);
    }

    protected CarBuilderWithSyntax(CarBuilderWithSyntax parent)
    {
        ParentBuilder = parent;
    }

    protected CarBuilderWithSyntax GetParentBuilder()
    {
        CarBuilderWithSyntax parentBuilder = this;

        while (parentBuilder.ParentBuilder != null)
        {
            parentBuilder = parentBuilder.ParentBuilder;
        }

        return parentBuilder;
    }

    public DoorBuilder WithDoor()
    {
        return new DoorBuilder(GetParentBuilder());
    }

    public CarBuilderWithSyntax WithEngine(int cmq)
    {
        if (ParentBuilder != null)
        {
            return GetParentBuilder().WithEngine(cmq);
        }

        // Save somewhere this information
        return this;
    }

    public Car Build()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public class DoorBuilder : CarBuilderWithSyntax
    {
        public DoorBuilder(CarBuilderWithSyntax builder)
            : base(builder)
        {
        }

        protected new DoorBuilder GetParentBuilder()
        {
            DoorBuilder parentBuilder = this;

            while ((parentBuilder.ParentBuilder as DoorBuilder) != null)
            {
                parentBuilder = parentBuilder.ParentBuilder as DoorBuilder;
            }

            return parentBuilder;
        }

        public DoorBuilder HavingSide(Sides side)
        {
            // Save side this information somewhere
            return GetParentBuilder();
        }

        public WindowBuilder WithWindow()
        {
            return new WindowBuilder(this);
        }

        public class WindowBuilder : DoorBuilder
        {
            public WindowBuilder(DoorBuilder builder)
                : base(builder)
            {
            }

            public WindowBuilder HavingWidth(int width)
            {
                // Terminal elements don't need to do the GetParentBuilder()
                return this;
            }

            public WindowBuilder HavingHeight(int width)
            {
                // Terminal elements don't need to do the GetParentBuilder()
                return this;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you only need to choose how/where to save the informations of the `Builder`... Note how the various classes interconnect, and the various `GetParentBuilder()` uses.

```
var car = CarBuilderWithSyntax.Create()
  .WithDoor()
      .HavingSide(Sides.Left)
      .WithWindow()
          .HavingWidth(50)
          .HavingHeight(50)
  .WithEngine(100)
  .Build();
```

Comment: Cool, that's a very clever and interesting way of how to do it :-) thank you!